# Insertar un formulario en medio de un archivo PHP

Tags: php

Quisiera poder insertar código html dentro de php de forma que pueda primero verificar que una sesión sea igual a un valor y si es verdadero que se muestre un formulario en html. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
        if($_SESSION["privilegio"] == 1)
        {
            echo "<p> Hola ".$_SESSION["user"]."</p>";
            // donde se quiere poner el formulario para agregar el nuevo usuario
        }
        # echo "<p>Éxito</p>";
        else
        {
            echo "<p>No tiene permisos para crear usuarios";
        }
    ?>
```

En donde esta el comentario sería donde se agregaría el código HTML para mostrar el formulario. De momento pienso que se puede hacer con un echo o con un print pero me gustaría hacerlo de otra manera.

Gracias por su atención.

Comment: Y cual es la razón para que lo quieras hacer de otra manera?

Comment: Para no tener que estar poniendo un echo enorme o muchos echos? Para ver si hay una forma un poco más eficiente que poner echo y concatenando líneas de html o poner en cada línea un echo.

Comment: Ok, entonces lo ideal sería usar la sintaxis alternativa, así no tienes que estar abriendo y cerrando llaves. ```<?php if(condicion): ?> ***aqui todo el código html que quieras*** <?php else: ?> ***aqui más codigo html *** <?php endif; ?>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías insertar el HTML *fuera* de PHP, cerrando el tag de PHP y abriéndolo luego. E.g.:

```php
<?php 
     if($_SESSION["privilegio"] == 1)
     {
         echo "<p> Hola ".$_SESSION["user"]."</p>";
?>
<form type="submit">
<input type="text" name="un-input-bonito" />
</form>
<?php
     }
     # echo "<p>Éxito</p>";
     else
     {
         echo "<p>No tiene permisos para crear usuarios";
     }
```

Solo recuerda que el código PHP debe ser consistente en todo el fichero, así esté partido (i.e. si abres una llave, debes cerrarla, etc.)

Comment: Funciona bien tu solución. Nada más como tu dices hay que mantener el orden para ver en donde abrir y cerrar la etiqueta php. Muchas gracias compañero.